# Customizing Azure Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, dashboard

We have created charts based on our identified KPIs and are planning to pin it to Dashboard. When we run query we see chart getting created as expected but when we pin check its rendering on Dashboard we are facing below issues -

1. The x-axis scale is always displayed vertical and has character limit during rendering
2. The x & y axis title are not displayed
3. All the charts are same blue color

Is there a fix or workaround for issues faced above?

Below link has reference to color change and titles but I dont see similar option available for me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-charts

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, you'd better provide a screenshot of the 2 charts:).

Comment: @IvanYang I have attached two images, the one with query is from LAWS and is exactly what I expect but when I pin it to Dashboard I see chart being rendered differently like the one in other image where the labels are rotated vertical and have character limit.Even if I add titles to axes it will not be reflected to Dashboard nor can I change color of this chart

Comment: cannot find a way for that:(.

Answer (score 1):

There's no workaround right now.
The good news are that we plan to change the visualization in the dashboard to be the exact same as the ones from where you pin the parts.
This will happen in the upcoming weeks.